# ConvertTo-HTML with Powershell Issue

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to output the value entered witin a textbox to HTML using PowerShell but i'm a little stuck. Here is my code:

```
$button1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$button1.Name = "button1"
$button1.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(16, 350)
$button1.Text = "Create"
$button1.add_Click({ConvertTo-HTML -title "Email Signature" -body "<p>$textBox2.Text</p>"})
```

The resulting HTML is...

```
System.Windows.Forms.TextBox, Text: Chris.Text
```

How can I make the output simply be "`Chris`"?

Comment: Worked it out :) The answer is: $($textBox2.Text)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worked it out :)

The answer is: $($textBox2.Text)

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the variable in either () or {} to retrieve the value when enclosed in "".

For example,

```
$button1.add_Click({ConvertTo-HTML -title "Email Signature" -body "<p>$($textBox2.Text)</p>"})
```

or

```
$button1.add_Click({ConvertTo-HTML -title "Email Signature" -body "<p>${textBox2.Text}</p>"})
```